# how can I get data in table format from pyodbc

Tags: python, pyodbc

I'm getting data from snowflake ODBC connection in python through below code - It gives me the data but its not in table format with column head.
How can I get it in table format with column head

```
import pyodbc
import sys

con = pyodbc.connect('DSN=Snowflake Conn')
con.setencoding(encoding='utf-8')
con.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_CHAR, encoding='utf-8')
cs=con.cursor()

query="select mr.entity_code as FUNDCODE, mr.AS_OF_DATE, mr.vol_contr_pc_abs * 3.549 EWMA_Vol_Annualised from risksd.tbl_market_risk mr join risksd.tbl_control_funds cf on cf.fundcode = mr.entity_code where model_code = 'GBL' and record_type = 'Portfolio' and mr.as_of_date ='"+last_business_day_string+"' and cf.fundcode in "+str(fundslist)
cs.execute(query)
while True:
    sf_data=cs.fetchone()
    if not sf_data:
        break
    print(sf_data)
```

I tried using sf_data = cs.fetch_pandas_all() function but this function is not available in pyodbc

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to viewing the data in a csv, then you can use the following after your "cs.execute(query)" line:

```
import os
import csv

# create a new csv file
filename = 'results'
with open(f'{filename}.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
  writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
  # write column heads to csv
  writer.writerow([column[0] for column in cs.desciption])
  # write data to csv
  while True:
      row=cs.fetchone()
      # if you're at the end of the data, break
      if row == None:
        break
      writer.writerow(row)
# open the csv file when done
os.startfile(f'{filename}.csv')
```